# Can the Chase test algorithm only modify attributes on the right side of a functional dependency?

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-theory, dependencies

I'm attempting to apply the Chase Algorithm to determine if a decomposition is a lossless join decomposition.

Functional Dependencies = {A → C, B → D, C → D, DE → C, CE → A}

Here is my initial matrix:

[image: Initial Matrix]

Can I apply DE → C to remove the subscript from e on the first two rows?  Since all c<sub>1</sub>'s are the same, then this means that e<sub>1</sub> and e<sub>2</sub> must be equivalent to e, correct?

[image: Second Matrix]

At this point, I would be able to set all c<sub>1</sub>'s equal to c, correct?  (Since, again, DE → C.)